# Where is the location of Release Artifacts on TFS/Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild

Can anybody tell me where the Release Artifact comes from when you use it in a Release Definition?

I’m currently using TFS on-prem (v15 Update 1) to handle undertake Build & Release. I believe this version is very close to what the current Azure DevOps documentation describes as  ‘Classic’.

I have a Build Definition that outputs an Artifact to the default local path on the agent (c:\agent_work\1\a) using the Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory. I also publish/copy the artifact to a network share.

I have a Release Definition which references the Build Definition as a Linked Artifact Source.  Therefore, when I create a new release where does the Release Definition get the Artifact Does it get it from my published network share? Does it get it from Source Control? How do I know it’s getting it from TFS or Network Share?

I know the Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory gets deleted on every build, so I know it can’t be from that location.

Comment: Have you tried `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`?

Comment: Although I answered your specific question, I'd be curious to know why this is relevant information to you -- the storage mechanism for these artifacts is intentionally designed to be transparent to the user.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for the info. The reason for asking is that I’m working with a client who is using a Release branch as a Dev branch. They are not able to change this, so I wanted to know where the release gets its artifacts. If it got them from TFS could potentially cause problems as they are constantly checking in changes. Based on your info I ran a test this morning placing a simple text file in the Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory and my network share. The release picked up the artifacts from the network share confirming your answer. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tied your release definition to a build definition. Build definitions can publish artifacts when they run.

Your release definition looks at a build run, looks at the artifacts it published, and then retrieves them from whatever location to which they were published. This *can* be a file share, or it can be within the TFS/Azure DevOps instance itself. Not source control or Azure Artifacts, but rather a completely internal store just for builds.

Now to directly answer your question:
How do you know where the artifact came from? By looking at the build run. How do you know where the artifacts are going to be published in the future? By looking at the build definition.